# Linq to Entities Group By Order By Not Working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query which I want to return a list of objects of type **tblcours**, like so

```
public IList<tblcours> GetAllLiveCoursesByUnitID(int id)
{
    Expression<Func<tblcours, bool>> predicate = x => x.tblCourseCategoryLinks.Any(cl => cl.tblUnitCategory.tblUnit.unitID == id);
    int headingId = 180;

    var distinctResult = from c in _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All
                             .Where(c => c.MainHeadingID != headingId)
                             .Where(predicate)
                             group c by c.MainHeadingID into uniqueIds
                             select uniqueIds.FirstOrDefault();

    return distinctResult.ToList();

}
```

What this query is doing, is getting a list of objects of type **tblcours** and then removing duplicate records with the same **MainHeadingID**. This works nicely, however, I also need to the returned data to be in alphabetical order, however, no matter what I try, I can't it to do so.

So far I have tried the following

```
distinctResult.OrderBy(c => c.CourseTitle);
return distinctResult.ToList();
```

But this never works, it just continues to return the list un-ordered.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
distinctResult= distinctResult.OrderBy(c => c.CourseTitle);
return distinctResult.ToList();
```

because OrderBy is returning ordered enumerable as [here is said](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx). Order by is not modyfing collection.

I highly recommend using resharper, he will catch such things and warn you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the return value of `OrderBy`:

```
return distinctResult.OrderBy(c => c.CourseTitle).ToList();
```

`OrderBy` doesn't order `distinctResult` in place. Instead, it returns a new enumerable that is ordered.